# Adding a polygon to a scatter plotly

Tags: r, polygon, plotly

I have 5 clusters of `x,y` data I'm plotting using `R`'s `plotly`.

Here are the data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(1,20,4),function(i) data.frame(x=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),y=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),cluster=i)))
```

Here's the plot:

```
library(plotly)
clusters.plot <- plot_ly(marker=list(size=10),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=~df$x,y=~df$y,color=~df$cluster,data=df) %>% hide_colorbar() %>% layout(xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F))

clusters.plot
```

[image]

Now I'm creating polygons around each cluster:

```
#helper functions:
library(data.table)
library(grDevices)

splinesPolygon <- function(xy,vertices,k=3, ...)
{
  # Assert: xy is an n by 2 matrix with n >= k.
  # Wrap k vertices around each end.
  n <- dim(xy)[1]
  if (k >= 1) {
    data <- rbind(xy[(n-k+1):n,], xy, xy[1:k, ])
  } else {
    data <- xy
  }
  # Spline the x and y coordinates.
  data.spline <- spline(1:(n+2*k), data[,1], n=vertices, ...)
  x <- data.spline$x
  x1 <- data.spline$y
  x2 <- spline(1:(n+2*k), data[,2], n=vertices, ...)$y
  # Retain only the middle part.
  cbind(x1, x2)[k < x & x <= n+k, ]
}

clustersPolygon <- function(df)
{
  dt <- data.table::data.table(df)
  hull <- dt[,.SD[chull(x,y)]]
  spline.hull <- splinesPolygon(cbind(hull$x,hull$y),100)
  return(data.frame(x=spline.hull[,1],y=spline.hull[,2],stringsAsFactors=F))
}

library(dplyr)
polygons.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$cluster),function(l) clustersPolygon(df=dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l)) %>% dplyr::rename(polygon.x=x,polygon.y=y) %>% dplyr::mutate(cluster=l)))
```

And now I want to add them to `clusters.plot`.

I thought this would do:

```
clusters <- unique(df$cluster)
for(l in clusters) clusters.plot <- clusters.plot %>% add_polygons(x=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.x,y=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.y,line=list(width=2,color="black"),fillcolor='transparent')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error: Columns `x`, `y` must be length 1 or 250, not 54, 54
```

`250` is `nrow(df)` and `54` is `nrow(dplyr::filter(polygonss.df,cluster == 1))`

Any idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding a polygon to a scatter plotly while retaining the hover info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48104724/adding-a-polygon-to-a-scatter-plotly-while-retaining-the-hover-info)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
for(l in clusters) clusters.plot <- clusters.plot %>% 
 add_polygons(x=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.x,
              y=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.y,
              line=list(width=2,color="black"),
              fillcolor='transparent', inherit = FALSE)
```

[image]