# Adding a polygon to a scatter plotly while retaining the hover info

Tags: r, hover, plotly

I have 5 clusters of `x,y` data I'm plotting using `R`'s `plotly`.

Here are the data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(1,20,4),function(i) data.frame(x=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),y=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),cluster=i)))
```

Here's their `plotly` scatter plot:

```
library(plotly)
clusters.plot <- plot_ly(marker=list(size=10),type='scatter',mode="markers",x=~df$x,y=~df$y,color=~df$cluster,data=df) %>% hide_colorbar() %>% layout(xaxis=list(title="X",zeroline=F),yaxis=list(title="Y",zeroline=F))
```

Which gives:
[image]

Then, following @Marco Sandri's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934438/adding-a-polygon-to-a-scatter-plotly), I add polygons circumscribing these clusters using this code:

Polygons code:

```
library(data.table)
library(grDevices)

splinesPolygon <- function(xy,vertices,k=3, ...)
{
  # Assert: xy is an n by 2 matrix with n >= k.
  # Wrap k vertices around each end.
  n <- dim(xy)[1]
  if (k >= 1) {
    data <- rbind(xy[(n-k+1):n,], xy, xy[1:k, ])
  } else {
    data <- xy
  }
  # Spline the x and y coordinates.
  data.spline <- spline(1:(n+2*k), data[,1], n=vertices, ...)
  x <- data.spline$x
  x1 <- data.spline$y
  x2 <- spline(1:(n+2*k), data[,2], n=vertices, ...)$y
  # Retain only the middle part.
  cbind(x1, x2)[k < x & x <= n+k, ]
}

clustersPolygon <- function(df)
{
  dt <- data.table::data.table(df)
  hull <- dt[,.SD[chull(x,y)]]
  spline.hull <- splinesPolygon(cbind(hull$x,hull$y),100)
  return(data.frame(x=spline.hull[,1],y=spline.hull[,2],stringsAsFactors=F))
}

library(dplyr)
polygons.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$cluster),function(l)
  clustersPolygon(df=dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l)) %>%
    dplyr::rename(polygon.x=x,polygon.y=y) %>%
    dplyr::mutate(cluster=l)))
```

And now adding the polygons:

```
clusters <- unique(df$cluster)

for(l in clusters) clusters.plot <- clusters.plot %>% 
 add_polygons(x=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.x,
              y=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.y,
              line=list(width=2,color="black"),
              fillcolor='transparent', inherit = FALSE)
```

Which gives:

[image]

Although this works great, unfortunately it eliminates the `hoverinfo` that existed prior to adding the polygons, and now is just the trace of each polygon.

Changing `inherit` from `FALSE` to `TRUE` results with the error I write about [in that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47934438/adding-a-polygon-to-a-scatter-plotly). So my question is how to add the polygons without changing the `hoverinfo` of the original plot.

Comment: The polygons hide the information underneath. Maybe you could replot the markers: clusters.plot %>% add_markers(x=~df$x,y=~df$y, showlegend = FALSE)

Comment: The hoverinfo is restored but now in addition to the polygons all points are connected by lines.

Comment: Try setting `hoverinfo="none"` to the `add_polygon` call

Comment: That just eliminated the "trace #of cluster" hoverinfo but didn't  recover the hoverinfo of the points.

Comment: Why not plotting the polygone before the markers? Also `polygons.df` is not properly defined, you missed some code lines there.

Comment: And, have you tried `fillcolor='none'`?

Comment: Can you edit your post to include the full contents of the line `polygons.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$cluster),function(l) `? Not quite able to reproduce `polygons.df` here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think part of the issue here is that the `colorbar` in `plotly` has some somewhat weird behavior and side effects when you start to mix and match trace types.

The simplest way to work around this *(and it seems appropriate since you are coloring by clusters, not a continuous variable)* is to change the class of your clustered column to be an ordered factor with the expression `df$cluster <- ordered(as.factor(df$cluster))`. *(I believe this could be in a dplyr mutate statement as well.)*

#### Packages and data generation functions

---

```
library(data.table)
library(grDevices)
library(dplyr)
library(plotly)

## Function Definitions 
splinesPolygon <- function(xy,vertices,k=3, ...) {
  # Assert: xy is an n by 2 matrix with n >= k.
  # Wrap k vertices around each end.
  n <- dim(xy)[1]
  if (k >= 1) {
    data <- rbind(xy[(n-k+1):n,], xy, xy[1:k, ])
  } else {
    data <- xy
  }
  # Spline the x and y coordinates.
  data.spline <- spline(1:(n+2*k), data[,1], n=vertices, ...)
  x <- data.spline$x
  x1 <- data.spline$y
  x2 <- spline(1:(n+2*k), data[,2], n=vertices, ...)$y
  # Retain only the middle part.
  cbind(x1, x2)[k < x & x <= n+k, ]
}

clustersPolygon <- function(df) {
  dt <- data.table::data.table(df)
  hull <- dt[,.SD[chull(x,y)]]
  spline.hull <- splinesPolygon(cbind(hull$x,hull$y),100)
  return(data.frame(x=spline.hull[,1],y=spline.hull[,2],stringsAsFactors=F))
}
```

#### Generate Data

---

The one critical difference here is to define your cluster as an ordered factor to keep it from being treated as a continuous variable that will invoke the `colorbar` weirdness.

```
set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(1,20,4),function(i) data.frame(x=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),y=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),cluster=i)))

## Critical Step here: Make cluster an ordered factor so it will
## be plotted with the sequential viridis scale, but will not 
## be treated as a continuous spectrum that gets the colorbar involved
df$cluster <- ordered(as.factor(df$cluster))

## Make hull polygons
polygons.df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(unique(df$cluster),function(l) clustersPolygon(df=dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l)) %>% dplyr::rename(polygon.x=x,polygon.y=y) %>% dplyr::mutate(cluster=l)))
clusters <- unique(df$cluster)
clustersPolygon(df=dplyr::filter(df,cluster == l)) %>% dplyr::rename(polygon.x=x,polygon.y=y) %>% dplyr::mutate(cluster=l)))
```

#### Build a `plotly` object

---

Mostly the same here, but starting by initializing an empty plotly object and then adding the hull polygons before the raw data points.

```
## Initialize an empty plotly object so that the hulls can be added first
clusters.plot <- plot_ly()

## Add hull polygons sequentially
for(l in clusters) clusters.plot <- clusters.plot %>% 
  add_polygons(x=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.x,
               y=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.y,
               name = paste0("Cluster ",l),
               line=list(width=2,color="black"),
               fillcolor='transparent', 
               hoverinfo = "none",
               showlegend = FALSE,
               inherit = FALSE)  

## Add the raw data trace
clusters.plot <- clusters.plot %>% 
  add_trace(data=df, x= ~x,y= ~y,color= ~cluster,
            type='scatter',mode="markers",
            marker=list(size=10)) %>% 
  layout(xaxis=list(title="X",
                    zeroline=F),
         yaxis=list(title="Y",
                    zeroline=F))
## Print the output
clusters.plot
```

#### Gives the following output

---

[image: polygons]

Answer (score 2):

This seems to give what you are looking for :

```
for(l in clusters) clusters.plot <- clusters.plot %>% 
  add_polygons(x=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.x,
           y=dplyr::filter(polygons.df,cluster == l)$polygon.y,
           line=list(width=2,color="black"),type = "contour",
           fillcolor='transparent', inherit = FALSE)
```

I add the

```
type = "contour"
```

Not sure the 
    fillcolor 
is needed anymore .. 
Does it fit your need ?

Comment: But it works for me .. what happen ? do you get an error message ?

Answer (score 2):

A bit work around. The `poly.df` file can be replaced by your data.frame. 
One can simply ggplot for visualisation and then transform by ggplotly.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

set.seed(1)
df <- do.call(rbind,lapply(seq(1,20,4), 
                           function(i) data.frame(x=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),y=rnorm(50,mean=i,sd=1),cluster=i)))
poly.df <- df %>% 
  group_by(cluster) %>%
  do(.[chull(.$x, .$y),]) 

ggplot(df, aes(x, y, colour = as.factor(cluster))) +
  geom_polygon(data = poly.df, fill = NA)+
  geom_point() ->
  p

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]