# Adding polygon to plotly scatterplot

Tags: r, plotly, polygon

I created a plotly scatterplot in R on which I would like to add a polygon.

[current plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MENnt.png)

This is the code I used to make the graph:

```
fig <- plot_ly(data = data, x= ~xbeak, y = ~ybeak, color = ~coordsbeak, text = ~paste(coordsbeak), type = 'scatter')
```

Now I want to add a polygon to this plot, which I tried with add_polygons. The polygon is a different dataframe, consisting two columns with 42  x and y coordinates.

```
fig <- fig %>% add_polygons(x = xym$x, y=xym$y)
```

However when I try to run this I get this error which I don't understand. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

> Error:
> ! Tibble columns must have compatible sizes.
> • Size 42: Columns `x` and `y`.
> • Size 11149: Columns `text` and `color`.
> ℹ Only values of size one are recycled.
> Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

Comment: The error message suggests that your data frames `xym`  and  `data` have different lengths. Your polygon is trying to get its colors from the coordsbeak column of `data` which is of a different length. Try setting e.g. color = "red" and text = "" inside add_polygons. Of course, this is just a guess, since you haven't included any data with which to reproduce the problem for ourselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions below. First, adding `inherit = FALSE` to `add_plygons()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
xym<-data.frame(y=c(3,4,4,3),
                x=c(5,5,6,6))
fig <- plot_ly(data = iris, x= ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, text = ~paste(Species), type = 'scatter', mode="markers")
fig <- fig %>% add_polygons(x = xym$x, y=xym$y, inherit = FALSE, showlegend = FALSE)
fig
```

Or, Switch the order of operations  - make the polygons first, then the scatterplot.

Here is an example with iris data:

```
xym<-data.frame(x=c(5,5,6,6),
                y=c(3,4,4,3))

# make an empty plot_ly object
fig <- plot_ly()
# add the polygons
fig<-fig %>% add_polygons(x = xym$x, y=xym$y)
# add the scatterplot
fig<-fig %>% add_trace(data = iris, x= ~Sepal.Length, y = ~Sepal.Width, color = ~Species, text = ~paste(Species), type ="scatter", mode="markers")
fig
```

referenced - [Adding a polygon to a scatter plotly while retaining the hover info](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48104724/10276092)
and [Adding a polygon to a scatter plotly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47934438/10276092)